# sqlite. Как создать атрибут типа Date

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

Глядя на уроки на просторах интернета вижу, что добавляют данные в базу используя `ContentValues`. Но конструктора принимающего тип Date там нет. Там небольшой список типов данных. 
  Я хотел создать таблицу, в которой есть столбец с датой и столбец с текстом. Думал поделить дату на 3 столбца. В одном год, в в другом месяц и в третьем дни. Но мне порекомендовали создать один столбец с атрибутом Date. Но как я понял sqLite не поддерживает подобных типов данных.
Хочу уточнить так ли это и как мне лучше поступить, если я создаю таблицу в которой есть разный текст на каждый день в течении нескольких лет. 
 Есть подозрение, что если добавить дату в таком формате ГГГГ-ММ-ДД в один столбец, то sqlite сможет делать выборку по дате.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дата в контексте программирования на Java - число миллисекунд после `01.01.1970 00:00 UTC`

Именно его и [храните](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13694823/3212712) в БД для дат. После извлечения из БД объект `Date` можно получить просто - `Date dateFromDb = new Date(longValueFromDb)`

Делать все возможные выборки по дате будет просто - вы будете делать выборки не по каким-то строкам в разных столбцах, но по числу в одном столбце.

Comment: а этот тип данных java.sql  на что ? не могу его использовать?  Иначе много возни. У меня дата с json берется в формате ДД-ММ-ГГГГ. Мне надо его перевести в миллисекунды, а потом обратно.  И разве не меньше процессорного времени понадобилось бы работая с таким ДД-ММ-ГГГГ как с датой? в миллисекундах куда больше цифр получается, а тут оперировать на уровне дней всего лишь

Comment: Недостатки хранения времени в STRING:
— Неэффективность использования памяти. В связи с тем, что в SQLite нет формата LONG, то системное время System.currentTimeMillis() полученное в LONG, при занесении в базу будет преобразован в INTEGER. В 32-битных системах под INTEGER выделяется 4 байта. Строковое представление времени в human readable формате явно занимает в разы больше памяти чем 4 байта.
— Неэффективный расход времени при выполнении выборок из базы. Сравнение двух строк происходит, очевидно, дольше сравнения двух чисел.

Comment: Нашел ответ.) со слов бывшего администатора СУБД oracle )

Comment: @Turalllb, я не думаю, что вам стоит гнаться за кол-вом тактов процессора при преобразовании дат. Да, вы можете хранить даты в виде строки. Да, сортировки так будут работать. Да, не нужно будет преобразовывать строку в дату и обратно. Но это нестандартное и плохо расширяемое решение. Представьте, что потом вам надо будет даты со временем хранить. Сравнение по строкам уже не будет нормально работать. А дата в виде числа всем будет понятна и годится во всех случаях. Ну и плюс всё из вашего коммента выше)

Comment: В общем я думаю ответ сводится к тому, что, если дата нужна для отображения в таблице, то строки удобнее, а если это информация, с которой будет производится работа (используется как ключ в таблице), то лучше в UNIX time. Ну и если требуется часовой пояс, то проще использовать строку, хотя тоже может зависеть от специфичности задачи.

Comment: На мой взгляд часовой пояс лучше в дате не хранить. Например, я не уверен, что сравнение дат будет работать для разных часовых поясов. Также, на мой взгляд, удобство человекочитаемости строковых дат менее важно чем более стандартное значение, если оно число и не зависит от часового пояса.

Comment: Ну не обязательно сравнивать даты разных часовых поясов. Например ситуация: В таблице список дат, в дате указано в каком часовом поясе задано время. Сортировка идет в пределах одного пояса, но зато человек  с другого часового пояса, сможет это время видеть с правильной коррекцией под его время.

Comment: А вообще как я увидел с Датой в временем существует много проблем и пока нет практической задачи, и если не собираешься писать на эту тему какую-нибудь работу, не стоит влезать в тонкости. Будет практическая задача и можно заниматься поиском решений.

Comment: ЮрийСПб, сделал правку в ответе. Unix время -это не миллисекунды, а секунды. И если в базу sqLite занести в миллисекундах и потом функцией strftime брать дату из базы, то получим время в таком формате '1970-01-01 00:00:00'

Comment: @Turalllb отклонил вашу правку, потому в Java это именно миллисекунды; посмотрите, например, [документацию System.currentTimeMillis()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29)

Answer (score 5):

Не поддержу категоричность ответа @ЮрийСПб

Согласно документации, SQLite, хотя и не имеет специального типа для хранения даты, но, поддерживает хранение даты и манипуляции с ними в одном из 3-х форматов:

1) **TEXT** как строку [ISO8601](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (`"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS"`).

2) **REAL** как [Юлианский](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0) номер дня с 24 ноября, 4714 д.н.э. GMT - согласно [пролептическому Григорианскому календарю](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C)

3) **INTEGER** в качестве Unix Time, количество секунд с `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`.

Если дата задана в одном из этих 3-х форматов, то поддерживается работа с встроенными в SQLite функциями работы с датами, а также задание в запросах операций `>, >=, <, <=, =, between`

Отдельно отмечу, что хранение даты в виде строки ISO8601, имеет один небольшой бесплатный бонусик, а именно становится возможным сохранение часового пояса в дате, чего как вы понимаете нет, когда мы храним UNIX time - иногда это важно.

Минусы, конечно же понятны: оверхед в хранении строки и лишние костЫ в конвертации.

Comment: Единственное, что я сейчас не понимаю, зачем тогда нужен класс sql.date. Я думал, что он создан для того, чтобы его можно было вписать в таблицу. Как я понимаю он имеет формат, такой же как в  ISO8601. Может используя этот класс можно в конце приписывать toString() и пихать в таблицу?