# Можно ли в DATA передать дату и время и чтобы они потом отобразислись в базе в столбце?

Tags: python, sqlite3

Бьюсь уже второй день, так и не нашел ответа. Можно ли в словарь DATA передавать дату и время, чтобы ни потом отобразились в столбце в базе данных?

```
import datetime

async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['day_time'] = datetime
        day_time = datetime.date.today()
        await state.update_data(
            {'day_time': day_time}
        )
```

У меня сейчас в базу данных передается 4 значения: id, username, name, phone

Если я делаю еще столбец, то данных не хватает и выкидывает ошибку

Весь код https://pastebin.com/VkC1jxtu

Подскажите, как сделать правильно?

Comment: Почитайте < https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/762847/sqlite-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0-date>

Comment: Написано как добавить столбец с датой < https://digitology.tech/posts/uchebnik-po-sqlite3-v-python/>